# Neo4j node api don't know how to find/get node by parameters not only id

Tags: node.js, neo4j, node-neo4j

i'm new to neo4j, i'm reading the documentation and a sample, small app based on the node module (neo4j), but i don't see a way to get a node or nodes based on parameter/r.

something like:

```
var node = db.find({user: "WillSmith@iam.com", password: "5@^632g23^@#23"});
```

Can anyone explane it to me, or point me to a good resource explaining it :)

Comment: Which node module did you look at?

Comment: The syntax you shown is for mongodb. It is not for neo4j

Comment: The module is "neo4j". The syntax is something i just write, i didn't see it anywhere ... i just want to make a point ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, if you want to find nodes by property, you should search in index.
This index you should create by yourself.

In this [file](https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j/blob/develop/lib/GraphDatabase._coffee#L179) i can see functions for working with indexes, unfortunately i've implemented this only in java, so i cant help with exact implementation. Hope, it helps =)

Comment: I was afraid that will happend :) i was hopping to not use indexis for this kind of search :/

Comment: Oh, i forgot about one option. You can try to execute cypher query. For example this query will return all nodes where type property's value is "ORGANIZATION" (case sensetive) and id property's value is 81  

"START n=node(*)
WHERE n.type="ORGANIZATION" AND n.id=81
RETURN n;"

Comment: mhm, this is also an viable option :)